# How do I make this jQuery not count sublists within a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I would like to know how many "root" steps are in an HTML list. I am going to be iterating through the root steps but the sub-steps are to be completely ignored.

My jQuery always counts the root `<li>` steps as well as the child `<li>` steps, but all I want is the root.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5x33omaw/1/

I want it to count only **3** steps instead of the **5** that it returns. How do I ignore the children?

**HTML:**

```
<ol id="sidebar-step-list" class="no-indent">
    <li>Step 1</li>
    <li>Step 2
        <ul>
            <li>Substep 1</li>
            <li>Substep 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Step 3</li>
</ol>
<hr/>
<div id="dog"></div>
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
var stepList = $("#sidebar-step-list li");
var length = stepList.length;

$("#dog").text("Number of steps: " + length);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add **>** sign

```
var stepList = $("#sidebar-step-list > li");
```

by adding >  will give you the direct li of #sidebar-step-list

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/5x33omaw/4/)